# How do I customize the documentation template of GhostDoc Pro?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, javadoc, ghostdoc

I don't like the standard **XML-Style** documentation of GhostDoc and would like to change it to something more inline with `JavaDoc` or at least to the standard way that Visual Studio adds comments in C# if you type `///`

So either:

```
/**
 * @brief Description
 *****************************************/
```

or:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
/// <summary> Description </summary>
//////////////////////////////////////////
```